# Can Google Analytics reports be poisoned?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Are Google Analytics reports vulnerable to having false data injected by malicious users?

Could a malicious user edit the Google Analytics javascript that runs on your page in order to put some false data in your reports to mislead you?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible.

JavaScript is a user-editable environment, and Google Analytics does not validate the data.

So, you could just inject JavaScript into the page to send any data you like to peoples' Google Analytics accounts, and there's no "validate" which data is valid and which isn't.

I can pop open DevTools Console on my chrome and just enter in Google Analytics data on any site that uses GA:

```
_gaq.push(["_trackPageview", "/anything-you-want-to-send"]);
```

This also applies to people "taking" your Google Analytics snippet to put on your site. Luckily, that type of hostile behavior is filterable, since you can configure Google Analytics to exclude data from foreign hostnames.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, even we had implemented this and had never crossed our mind, maybe this will help to fix it. I must try the duplicate profile and understand it more...

https://web.archive.org/web/20120530210930/http://techhacking.com/2011/01/23/google-analytics-referrer-spammers/